# How to find a conditional probability using copula-based Markov process?

Tags: time-series, markov-process, copula, risk

I have a monthly time series of a water quality parameter. I used copula-based Markov process of C(Y(t), Y(t-1) and I forecasted the mean behavior of Yt by following equation:
[image]

Now, I need to find the probability that for a given month, my water quality (Yt) will be lower than a predefined value (a critical value that has been set up by regulations).
Can you please help me how to find this probability?

If there are methods other than copula-based Markov process that I can use please share it with me.

I used this paper as my reference: [Chen, X., Fan, Y., 2006, Estimation of copula-based semiparametric time series models](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0304407605000783)